# Assistance with DPLYR functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make my code display the mean attendance of a specified country in a new column. When I run the code below (Should be an image) I get the table also listed in the image. Can anyone explain how to display only the column of the specified country name and the mean attendance in the new column and explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you

[My_Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAspC.png)

EDIT: sorry I'm obviously new at this,
my code is

```
WorldCupMatches %>%   
  select(Home.Team.Name, Attendance) %>% 
  group_by(Home.Team.Name == "USA") %>% 
  mutate(AVG_Attendance = mean(Attendance, na.rm = T))
```

so to explain more, worldcupmatches is a dataframe and it has columns named "home.team.names" and "Attendance." I am trying to add a column by mutating and I want the mutated column to show the mean attendance for a country. The country i am looking for in this particular situation is USA. I also want the output to only display the columns "home.team.name" (with the USA as the home team), attendance and the mutated column that would be the mean attendance.

Thank you all for the help i got a lot of great answers!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not share code or data as an image because we can't easily run that ourselves. If you want to limit records use the `filter()` dplyr verb rather than trying to filter in the `group_by` verb,

Comment: Looks like you want `filter` instead of `group_by` and `summarise` instead of `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

First group by `Home.Team.Name`

Then you get the mean of each country in the table with `summarise`

If you just want USA then add `filter(Home.Team.Name == "USA")` at the end

```
WorldCupMatches %>% 
  select(Home.Team.Name, Attendance) %>% 
  group_by(Home.Team.Name) %>% 
  summarise(AVG_Attendance = mean(Attendance, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  filter(Home.Team.Name == "USA")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have averages by group just `group_by`and `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Hometeam) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Attendance))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Hometeam  mean
* <chr>    <dbl>
1 France    555 
2 UK        500.
3 USA       373
```

If you're just interested in a specific group you can `filter` that group:

```
df %>%
  filter(Hometeam=="USA") %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Attendance))
  mean
1  373
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Hometeam = c("USA", "UK", "USA", "France", "UK", "USA"),
  Attendance = c(120, 333, 222, 555, 666, 777)
)
```